# Retrieve DOM element according to the number of its children

Tags: javascript, arrays, count

I want to get the DOM elements that have more than 5 children and add a class name to only those elements. For example,

```
<div class="parent">
    <span>child</span>
    <span>child</span>
    <span>child</span>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <span>child</span>
    <span>child</span>
    <span>child</span>
    <span>child</span>
    <span>child</span>
    <span>child</span>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <span>child</span>
    <span>child</span>
</div>
```

In this case I'd like to add a class name to the second `div` above that has 6 children `spans`.

I've tried the following:

```
const parents = document.querySelector(".parent");

if (parents.childElementCount > 5) {
    parents.classList.add('reduce-size');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const parents = document.querySelectorAll(".parent");

parents.forEach(el => {
 if(el.childNodes.length > 5){
   el.classList.add('.reduce-size');
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 div with the class parent. So I think you have to use a querySelectorAll('.parent') and a loop after. Someting like this maybe

```
const parents = document.querySelectorAll(".parent");
for (let i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {
  if (parents[i].childElementCount > 5) {
  cityLocationTitle.classList.add('.reduce-size');
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/querySelector) only returns the first matching element. You need to use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/querySelectorAll) together with a loop:

```js
const parents = document.querySelectorAll(".parent");

for (let parent of parents) {
  if (parent.childElementCount > 5) {
      console.log("do stuff here");
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <span>child</span>
    <span>child</span>
    <span>child</span>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <span>child</span>
    <span>child</span>
    <span>child</span>
    <span>child</span>
    <span>child</span>
    <span>child</span>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <span>child</span>
    <span>child</span>
</div>
```